# Adding record set values to stored procedure parameters - Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to each row to my stored procedure parameters. My record-set has 6 columns and I am using record-set to retrieve the values of those columns and add them to stored proc. I am stuck at below unable to retrieve column values of my record-set.
Do you think What I am doing below is right or is there any other way to retrieve a column value from a record-set

```
If not rs.EOF and rs.BOF Then               
                For Each col in rs.Fields               
                    rsAdd(Replace(col.Name,"_","")) = col.Value
                    cmd.Parameters("@id") = col.Name(Replace(col.Name,"_","")).value
                Next            
        End If
```

UPDATE: This is what I have done after Josh advised me on hard coding all values to parameters.

This is not executing stored procedure. But I know that my stored proc works as I have executed it with sample data in SSMS.

The Record set has data so I guess something is wrong in the code.

```
Set rs = GetRecordSet("C:\upload\new\" & TheNewFileName2)
    'Response.Write "No Errors"
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString="DSN=ABCD"
    cn.Open
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = 4     
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[uspSearchData]"       


    While not rs.EOF and rs.BOF 

                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@id",3,1,rs("Merchant_ID"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name",200,1,255,rs("Name"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@address",200,1,255,rs("Address"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@city",200,1,255,rs("City"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@state",200,1,255,rs("State"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@zip",200,1,255,rs("Zip"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@country",200,1,255,rs("Country")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@phone",200,1,255,rs("Phone")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@emailid",200,1,255,rs("Web_Address")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@awardlevel",200,1,255,rs("Award_Level")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@awardvalue",200,1,255,rs("Award_Value"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@awarddays",200,1,255,rs("Award_Days"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@bestlogo",200,1,255,rs("BestLogo")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@twitter",200,1,255,rs("Twitter"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@facebook",200,1,255,rs("Facebook")) 
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@electronicprogram",200,1,255,rs("Electronic_Program"))

                cmd.Execute
                rs.MoveNext         
    Wend

    rs.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Any specific error that you are getting ?

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar no error. The application runs but database is not executed. All the connection string are accurate though. I have updated the code to use stored proc but it fails too.

Comment: if it's not updating, i presume an error is occurring. do you get an error?

Comment: No I am not getting any error.

Comment: double check, put the following right before your while loop: on error goto 0

Comment: Why do you have a test .. and rs.BOF in the while loop? Surely you should only need While Not rs.EOF

Comment: `While Not rs.EOF And rs.BOF ` is the same as `While (Not rs.EOF) And rs.BOF `, so you're probably now even entering the loop.  You probably meant `While Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF `

Comment: You won't get BOF = True if you haven't used MovePrevious. When the RS is opened is is positioned on the first record, so you only need to test on rs.EOF. Thats why you do not get any records - BOF and EOF are both False on the first record, so the while loop exits immediately.

Comment: If you don't get any error it means you catch errors either in the ASP level (On Error Resume Next), or in the database level, in the stored procedure itself. Check this out, and let me know please.

Comment: @TimWilliams@JohnRC Thanks guys. That helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was checking for End of file and if not EOF then go inside the loop. But there is BOF as well I was not checking for "Not BOF" and that is the reason, values are not inserting into database. My final working code is below.

```
Set rs = GetRecordSet("C:\upload\new\" & TheNewFileName2)
    'Response.Write "No Errors"
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString="DSN=ABCD"
    cn.Open
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = 4     
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[uspSearchData]"       


    While not rs.EOF and not rs.BOF 

                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@id",3,1,rs("Merchant_ID"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name",200,1,255,rs("Name"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@address",200,1,255,rs("Address"))
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@city",200,1,255,rs("City"))
                .
                .
                .
                .
                cmd.Execute
                rs.MoveNext         
    Wend

    rs.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think What I am doing below is right or is there any other way
>   to retrieve a column value from a record-set

if you only have 6 columns, you're better off just hard coding each line instead of using a loop to go through each column. Looping through each column will ONLY work if they are all of the same data type and size